# Keep window on top WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have problem to keep Window on TOP ? I work with MVVM WPF

I have this code in ConfigRole Model:

```
if (!System.Windows.Application.Current.Windows.OfType<ConfigRole>().Any())
{                 
    ConfigRoleModel configRoleModel = new ConfigRoleModel();
    ConfigRole winconfigRole = new ConfigRole();
    winconfigRole.DataContext = configRoleModel;
    winconfigRole.Show();
    winconfigRole.Topmost = true;
    winconfigRole.Focus();
}
```

Here the new Window is Correct, it is on TOP,

but after that, I want to show other Window on TOP from ConfigRoleModel ,
this is code ConfigRoleModel :

```
if (!System.Windows.Application.Current.Windows.OfType<ButtonListView>().Any())
{                 
    ButtonListViewModel buttonListViewModel = new ButtonListViewModel();
    ButtonListView winconfigRole = new ButtonListView();
    winconfigRole.DataContext = buttonListViewModel;

    winconfigRole.Show();
    winconfigRole.Topmost = true;
    winconfigRole.Focus();
}
```

So ,here I don't have this new Window on TOP! 
I don't understand! it is the same code like the first ..

I try also with `winconfigRole.ShowDialog();` 
and `Window.activate()

And the same Problem!

How can I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Set Owner to configRoleModel

Comment: that is the acorrect answer, very thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `Owner` property the `ConfigRole` to the `MainWindow` (or whatever window you open it from) and the `Owner` property of `ButtonListView` to the `ConfigRole` window:

```
if (!System.Windows.Application.Current.Windows.OfType<ButtonListView>().Any())
{
    ButtonListViewModel buttonListViewModel = new ButtonListViewModel();
    ButtonListView winconfigRole = new ButtonListView();
    winconfigRole.DataContext = buttonListViewModel;
    winconfigRole.Owner = System.Windows.Application.Current.Windows.OfType<ConfigRole>().FirstOrDefault(); //<--
    winconfigRole.Show();
    winconfigRole.Topmost = true;
    winconfigRole.Focus();
}
```